# How to insert elements into specific index in a 2D array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an object that looks like below

```
const tableData = [
    {
        
        "Location": "London",
        "Status": "Unknown"
    },
    {
        
        "Location": "Delhi",
        "Status": "Reachable"
    },
    {
        
        "Location": "Berlin",
        "Status": "Unknown"
    },
    {
        
        "Location": "Tokyo",
        "Status": "Busy"
    },
]
```

Now I want to create a 2D array which will hold this information in a certain way. Here is my code below

```
const statusOrder = {"Reachable": 0, "Busy": 1, "Unknown": 2}
let statusOrderInfo = Array(Object.keys(statusOrder).length).fill([]);
for(let i=0; i< tableData.length; i++) {
    const status = tableData[i]["Status"].trim()
    const statusIndex = statusOrder[status]
    statusOrderInfo[statusIndex].push(tableData[i])
}
console.log(statusOrderInfo)
```

As you can see I want each item of the `tableData` object to be in a certain index of the 2D array. So the item that contains `Status` as `Reachable` should be at index 0, the item that contains the `Status` as `Busy` should be at index 1 and so on.

So the final output should look like

```
[
   [
      {
         "Location":"Delhi",
         "Status":"Reachable"
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "Location":"Tokyo",
         "Status":"Busy"
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "Location":"London",
         "Status":"Unknown"
      },
      {
         "Location":"Berlin",
         "Status":"Unknown"
      }
   ]
]
```

But I get a wrong output on running the above code even though I am targeting the correct index. What's wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix on your problem is that just changing your manner to set initial value of `statusOrderInfo` and use `Array.from` instead of `Array.fill` like this:

```
let statusOrderInfo = Array.from({length: Object.keys(statusOrder).length}, ()=> []);
```

another solution is set initiali value of `statusOrderInfo` by empty array, and then in your for loop, after you get the index of current object based on `status` value, you can  check if  `statusIndex` already exist in the `statusOrderInfo` or not, like this:

```
const statusOrder = {"Reachable": 0, "Busy": 1, "Unknown": 2}
let statusOrderInfo = [];
for(let i=0; i< tableData.length; i++) {
    const status = tableData[i]["Status"].trim()
    const statusIndex = statusOrder[status];
    if(statusOrderInfo[statusIndex]) statusOrderInfo[statusIndex].push(tableData[i]);
    else statusOrderInfo[statusIndex] = [ tableData[i] ]
}
console.log(statusOrderInfo);
```

another solution, is to use `reduce` method on array, like this:

```js
const tableData = [{

    "Location": "London",
    "Status": "Unknown"
  },
  {

    "Location": "Delhi",
    "Status": "Reachable"
  },
  {

    "Location": "Berlin",
    "Status": "Unknown"
  },
  {

    "Location": "Tokyo",
    "Status": "Busy"
  },
];
const statusOrder = {"Reachable": 0, "Busy": 1, "Unknown": 2}
const result = tableData.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const index = statusOrder[cur.Status];
  if (acc[index]) acc[index].push(cur);
  else acc[index] = [cur]
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const 
  tableData = [ { "Location": "London", "Status": "Unknown" }, { "Location": "Delhi", "Status": "Reachable" }, { "Location": "Berlin", "Status": "Unknown" }, { "Location": "Tokyo", "Status": "Busy" } ],
  statusOrder = {"Reachable": 0, "Busy": 1, "Unknown": 2};

const statusOrderInfo = tableData.reduce((list, e) => {
  const index = statusOrder[e.Status];
  list[index] = [...(list[index] || []), {...e}];
  return list;
}, []);

console.log(statusOrderInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Anoter one solution in kind of declartive way:

First of all sort objects by status code using [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

And then just wrap every object to it own array using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const tableData = [{Location: "London",Status: "Unknown"},{Location: "Delhi",Status: "Reachable"},{Location: "Berlin",Status: "Unknown"},{Location: "Tokyo",Status: "Busy"}]
const statusOrder = {Reachable: 0, Busy: 1, Unknown: 2}

const result = tableData
  .sort(({ Status: s1 }, { Status: s2 }) => statusOrder[s1] - statusOrder[s2])
  .map((item) => [item]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others explained, [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) would be the best choice for your scenario. Because on every iteration you would create a new Array object.

```js
const tableData = [{ Location: "London", Status: "Unknown" }, { Location: "Delhi", Status: "Reachable" }, { Location: "Berlin", Status: "Unknown" }, { Location: "Tokyo", Status: "Busy" }]
const statusOrder = { "Reachable": 0, "Busy": 1, "Unknown": 2 };

const statusOrderInfo = tableData.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  const index = statusOrder[currentValue.Status];
  if (accumulator[index]) {
    accumulator[index].push(currentValue);
  } else {
    accumulator[index] = [currentValue];
  }
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(statusOrderInfo);
```

##### Explanation for what's going on in your code:

As you have used `[].fill([])` to fill the Array. It would create only one empty Array object and use it to initialize the actual array. That's why the following snippet behaves the way it should behave :)

```
const statusOrderInfo = Array(3).fill([]);
statusOrderInfo[0].push(10);

console.log(statusOrderInfo);
/* Results:
[
  [ 10 ],
  [ 10 ],
  [ 10 ]
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution:

```js
let statuses = ["Reachable", "Busy", "Unknown"];
const tableData = [
    {"Location": "London", "Status": "Unknown"},
    {"Location": "Delhi", "Status": "Reachable" },
    {"Location": "Berlin", "Status": "Unknown"},
    {"Location": "Tokyo", "Status": "Busy"}
];

let result = statuses.map(status => tableData.filter(tableDataItem => tableDataItem.Status == status));
console.log(result);
```